# Selecting wildcard child class and adding class to parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I want to select the `a` that is the parent of the `img` whose `class` has `blah-3-*` with `*` being a wildcard since it could be any number. Then I want to add the class `gallery` to the `a` parent.

```
<div class="content">
    <a href="link">
        <img src="blah.jpg" class="blah-1 blah-2 blah-3-01">
    </a>
</div>
```

So after the code is executed, the `a href` should have `class="gallery"` added to it.

This is my nonworking code:

`$('.content a > img[class^='blah-3'').parent().attr('class', 'gallery');`

Code doesn't work, and it gives me an unexpected identifier error.

What is wrong with my code? Could someone please educate me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fix Quotes and brackets. 
You need wildcard selector `*` instead of startswith selector `^`

```
$('.content a > img[class*=blah-3]').parent().attr('class', 'gallery');
```

or

```
$('.content a > img[class*=blah-3]').closest('a').attr('class', 'gallery');
```

You can also use .addClass if your `a` has other classes. If the class is already present `.addClass` won't add it again.

```
$('.content a > img[class*=blah-3]').closest('a').addClass('gallery');
```

Comment: I have actually tried that. For some reason none of these are working. I keep getting `Syntax Error: Unexpected identifier`.

My original code works `$('.content a > img').parent().attr('class', 'gallery');` but I want to be more specific with selecting an `img` class.

Comment: There was something wrong with a plugin causing the disturbance. Thanks!